# Move start point of arc and calculate new center

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I have part of a circle described by three two dimensional vectors.

- start point `s1`
- center point `c1`
- end point `e`

I move the start point `s1` by `m1`, which is a **known** two dimensional vector. My question is: Can I calculate the new center point `c2` from the data I have? And if so, how?

Problem

[image]

I'm creating a svg-manuipulation-app (drawing-app) in javascript where I want to edit one point of an arc, but keep the shape of the arc intact by appropriately moving the center of the arc.

It only looks like I want to keep the `x` value the same. Small coincidence I didn't realised. The question should cover any vector `m1`, no matter where the new center `c2` would end up.

Comment: If you save shape (angular measure) of arc then answer is "almost yes". You can calculate angular measure of arc as angle between 2D-vectors connecting center with start and end. You can get `c2` from two conditions: `c2` is equidistant from `s2` and `e` and angle between 2D-vectors connecting new center with new start and end is the same as for old start and old center. The only possible problem is that there are two locations of `c2` satisfying these conditions. If you need something like continuity you can select solution which is closer to old center position.

Comment: I recommend try use not 2D vectors but complex numbers for these calculations.

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I will assume that you want to generate the new arc such that its subtended angle at the center is the same as the starting one.

From $\mathbf{s_1}$ , $\mathbf{e_1}$, and $\mathbf{c_1}$, the signed angle is computed as

$ \theta =\sin^{-1} \dfrac{ \big[ \mathbf{(s_1 - c_1) \times (e_1 - c_1)} \big]_z }{\|\mathbf{ s_1 - c_1} \| \| \mathbf{e_1 - c_1 }\| } $

where the numerator is the $z$ coordinate of the cross product, and the $2D$ vectors $\mathbf{s_1, e_1} $ and $ \mathbf{c_1} $ are appended with $0$ as their $z$-coordinate, to turn them into $3D$ vectors.

From this and using a $2D$ rotation matrix (applied to $2D$ vectors this time, by disregarding the $0$ $z$-coordinate), we have

$ \mathbf{e_1} = \mathbf{c_1} + \mathbf{R} (\mathbf{s_1} - \mathbf{c_1})$

where the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ is given by

$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) && - \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) && \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix} $

When we move $\mathbf{s_1}$ to $\mathbf{s_2}$, and keeping $\mathbf{e_1}$ the same, then you want to find $\mathbf{c_2}$ such that

$ \mathbf{e_1} = \mathbf{c_2} + \mathbf{R} ( \mathbf{s_2} - \mathbf{c_2} ) $

Re-arranging,

$ \mathbf{e_1} - \mathbf{R} \mathbf{s_2} = ( \mathbf{I } - \mathbf{R} ) \mathbf{c_2} $

Now the matrix $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{R})$ is always non-singular unless $\theta = 0$, that is, in the case of no arc at all, and this case can be ignored.

Thus, from the above equation, we can solve for $\mathbf{c_2} $ as follows

$ \mathbf{c_2} = ( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{R} )^{-1} \big( \mathbf{e_1} - \mathbf{R} \mathbf{s_2} \big) $

The following animation shows how a sequence of $\mathbf{c_2}$ is generated by varying the starting point $\mathbf{s}$ using this formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you add another constraint about the center, since given $s_2,e $ the center is at a position which is equidistant to those two other points. Therefore, if $s_2 = (x_s,y_s)$, $e = (x_e,y_e)$, then $c_2 = (x_2,y_2)$ where

$$(x_s-x_2)^2+(y_s-y_2)^2 = (x_e-x_2)^2+(y_e-y_2)^2$$

$$x_s^2-2x_2x_s+x_2^2 + y_s^2 -2*y_sy_2 + y_2^2  = x_e^2-2x_2x_e+x_2^2 + y_e^2 -2*y_ey_2 + y_2^2$$

$$x_s^2 + y_s^2-x_e^2-y_e^2 = 2(x_2(x_s-x_e)+y_2(y_s-y_e))$$.

Since $x_2, y_2$ are our only unknowns, we end up with one equation with two unknowns, which is unsolvable.

However, based on your picture it looks like you want  the x value of $c_1$ to be the same as the x value of $c_2$. If that is true, then simply plug in the x value for $c_1$ as $x_2$ and solve for $y_2$ to get your solution

Comment: It only looks like I want to keep the `x` value the same. Small coincidence I didn't realised.